# How to schedule an R script on MacOS monthly in CronR

Tags: r, schedule

I'm trying to use CronR to schedule a script to run monthly on my MacOS on the first of the month. Not quite sure what's wrong with the code.

When I use the following, it runs monthly on the first but ALSO weekly on mondays at the same time

`cron_add(command=cmd, frequency = "monthly", at="07:05", days_of_month = 'first', id = 'EARS', description = "Absence Report")`

I tried adding in a clarifier for days_of_week = "*" but now it runs daily

`cron_add(command=cmd, frequency = "monthly", at="07:05", days_of_month = 'first', days_of_week = "*", id = 'EARS', description = "Absence Report")`

Answer (score 0):

Oh wow ok I think I may have fixed it. If anyone's curious:

```
cron_add(command=cmd, frequency = "monthly", at="07:05",
 days_of_month = 'first', id = 'EARS', description = "Absence Report")
```

generates a cron job with the frequency "5 7 1 * 1" suggesting it's assuming a default days_of_week = "1"

```
cron_add(command=cmd, frequency = "monthly", at="07:05",
 days_of_month = 'first', days_of_week = "*", id = 'EARS',
 description = "Absence Report")
```

generates a cron job with the frequency "5 7 1 * 0,1,2,3,4,5,6" suggesting that it thinks I want it to run every day of the week and oh baby it's doing exactly that

When I enter the command:

```
cron_add(command=cmd, frequency = '5 7 1 * *', id = 'EARS', 
     description = "Absence Report")
```

It seems to result in the desired frequency. I'll keep y'all posted if it actually works!